# JVM getting colder after initial warmup

Tags: jvm

We are trying to build a low latency system using Java.

As part of fine tuning, we do the initial warm up of the application during startup to go above the default compile threshold 10000. We could see that any live processing latency immediately after the warmup looks better. The latency looks good when the system is continuously processing events. But when the system goes back to idle state where there is no events coming for 10 minutes, the latency starts degrading.

I initially thought it could be JVM evicting the generated code from the cache. I have set a higher size for code cache and enabled events of code cache and noticed that the code cache is not even reaching 50% capacity.

Any idea what could be the issue? Basically the initial warm up during start up goes in vain once the system goes into idle mode for a short duration.

Comment: I'd suggest trying `-XX:+PrintCompilation` as well as experimenting with tools like `jcmd` (there's `Compiler.codecache` and `Compiler.codelist` command) and JMC/JFR (Java Flight Recorder). You can run JFR while the app is running with a very-low overhead (~1%).

Comment: Profiler is your best friend. Most often performance problems are hidden in the application rather than in JVM.